# Background color is seen while performing dojo transition

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

There is a problem in my app.I am using worklight v 6.0 and dojo framework.For testing i am using galaxy tab 2 . There is a white space coming between two header when transition occurs. What should i do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Screen shot? Code snippet to reproduce?

Comment: The error is during transition .So i could not capture it easily . Regarding snippet it just a dojo transition function.

Comment: It would help to reproduce your problem if you provide a small test case. Should we write code from zero or should you provide it...? it makes more sense if you provide it as you are experiencing a problem.

Comment: just now found out that the space was not from the header ,it was from the body space

Comment: @Idan Adar This is not resolved. The problem is when i try to access the dynamic data then the two page that is under page transition is having a space between them.So do you have any idea how to debug it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47676/discussion-between-balaji-sabdhar-m-and-idan-adar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi

The background color is set to header color. So that when the transition happens the white screen is not seen.

Answer (score 1):

By reducing the width of the first page you can reduce this error.